# Working with values in lists

Tags: r

I have a list containing 3 vectors.

```
mylist <- list( a = c(1,2),
                b = c(3,4),
                c = c(5,6) )
```

Is there any simple way to, for instance, perform computations on the first values of the three objects with the `sum()` function?

I tried many things like:

```
sum(mylist[c(a, b, c)][1])
```

This line of code does not work, but it gives insight into what I am trying to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `sapply`

```
> sum(sapply(mylist, "[", 1))
[1] 9
```

Bonus fun fact:  You can use `c( )` inside of `[[ ]]`:

```
sum( sapply(seq(mylist), function(i) mylist[[ c(i, 1) ]]) )
```

Comment: In the second line of code, does R automatically assume that `i` takes on the values `1`, `2` and `3`?

Comment: @SavedByJESUS, those are the values, but not "automatically".   `i` takes on the values of whatever is in the first argument of `sapply`, in this case `seq(mylist)` which generates an integer for each element in the list.

Comment: I'm still amazed at the "[" argument in the `sapply` function, which appears nowhere in the help file. Thanks to your answer, I now know it and am working better with lists.

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient solution:

```
 sum(unlist(lapply(mylist,'[',1)))
 [1] 9
```

Comment: if you are going to use `unlist`, you should turn off `use.names`